# Bluetooth socket turning null when entering IOEx catch block (android 4)

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, try-catch

My software worked fine for some time but with Android 4 some new issues pop up.

(Device Samsung Note with Android 4.0.4)

the following runs inside some loop in/on its on thread

```
try {
    socket.connect();     // <-- this blocks for up to 6 sec

} catch (IOException e) { // <-- this was entered
    try {
        socket.close();   // <-- here the NPE happened
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //stuff
    }

} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    //stuff
}
```

I made the experience that the socket could turn null while blocking on connect, but recently i even caught it being null inside the IOEx catch block. So the connect threw an IOEx and not a NPE, so the socket still was there. Inside the catch block the socket.close() then threw a NPE crashing the Service because i didnt use a NPE catch there.

Imho it just doesnt make sense to put a NPE catch block inside another catch block that requires the object to be alive in the first place.

This all is happening more and more with android 4 and most of the time when the service (and the app) is running in the background for some time. Its not a market app, so its ok if its still active after hitting the home button. But once its in the background for too long, the (unconnected!) socket is being gc'ed it seems.

Question is: why is this happening ? and should i really put a NPE catch in addition to the inner IOEx ?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed issues with Android ICS on Bluetooth too. 
Android ICS introduced some security bugfixes to Bluetooth, as they claim (and even more bugs).

So, I would report it on the Android [bugtracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). It may be relevant to check other devices, to see if it's Samsung's Bluetooth stack or the Android code.

It may also be relevant to check the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34161&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) reported by me on the Android Bugtracker, although I had problems with pairing..